# how to hide "skipped tests" on phpunit

Tags: phpunit

With PHPUnit you can skip tests by calling `self::markTestSkipped('...')`. I mainly do this when optional extensions aren't available. But is there a way to exclude these from PHPUnits output?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can "hide" or not show those messages or ignore that test by using `markTestSkipped`, but you can use [`@require`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/incomplete-and-skipped-tests.html#skipping-tests-using-requires) to ignore tests that do not meet a condition (not any).

For example, using `@require extension redis >= 2.2.0` will literally skip that test if you don't have `redis >= 2.2.0`.

I still think it is not exactly what you want, but may be more helpful